# fricative s v of others followed by a other Consonant phonetic symbols, can we just drop the frictive sound?

Tags: word-choice

fricative s v of others followed by a other Consonant phonetic symbols, can we just drop the frictive sound?
For example:

- a bottle of water
- bounce the ball
- so many times before

Comment: I don’t understand this question. Can you make the examples more detailed?

Comment: @Xanne is right, the question is not at all clear.

Comment: You can nearly always drop the /v/ in *of*; that's because it's a function word with a weak form /ə/ used before consonants. You cannot drop the /v/ in *love words*, which also has /v/ followed by /w/.